# dotnet build does not generate runtimeconfig.json and deps.json if a solution does not contain all referenced projects

Tags: .net, build, msbuild

dotnet build does not generate a runtimeconfig.json and deps.json if a solution does not contain all referenced projects.

I created a small example solution that shows the problem. It contains 3 projects. A console project and 2 library projects. Lib2 depends on Lib1. And both libraies depend on the console project, because the console project is supposed to perform checks on the libraries. Lib2 runs the console project as a post build target. CheckTest.sln contains all 3 projects. CheckTest2.sln only contains the console and the Lib2 project. The Lib1 project is still referenced by Lib2.

You can find the code here: https://github.com/gauss-lvs-dev/build-runtimeconfig-test

If I run `dotnet build CheckTest.sln` the build succeeds. If I run `dotnet build CheckTest2.sln` the build fails because the runtimeconfig.json and deps.json are not created and the console program cannot be executed. Even when I run `dotnet build CheckTest2.sln` right after `dotnet build CheckTest.sln` the build fails. The runtimeconfig.json and deps.json are beeing deleted somehow.

In the real world our main solution has over 80 projects, but most colleagues are working only in 2 or 3 projects, which is why we want to create additional solutions that contains only those 2 or 3 projects. We also want to be able to only build those 2 or 3 projects separatly, since the are placed far back in the build process.

I also forced the generation of the runtimeconfig.json by adding     <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles> in the Check.csproj file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include all relevant details here, as formatted text, as a [mcve], not by linking elsewhere. Links can break, or linked content can change (especially on github!), making the question useless for others with similar problems.

Comment: You describe that the Lib1 and Lib2 projects are executing the built executable of the console project as a build step -- that's not a link dependency. Yes, the build step has a dependency on the console executable but the libs don't have a link dependency on the console app and the console app doesn't have a link dependency on the libs. They don't have `ProjectReference`s to each other. In the solution file you can add build dependencies to ensure that the console project is built first to ensure that it is ready for the build steps in the lib projects. (The build step is not in the example.)

Comment: The question may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).